# Is there a dynamic text method in ArcGIS Pro to mandate the display of trailing zeros in map coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, dynamic-text

I am interested in showing map center coordinates on a layout in ArcGIS Pro using dynamic text:

```
<dyn type="mapFrame" name="MapName" property="center.y" units="dd" decimalPlaces="4" showDirections = "False"/>, <dyn type="mapFrame" name="MapName" property="center.x" units="dd" decimalPlaces="4" showDirections = "False"/>
```

This gives me, for example: 36.8101°, -76.612°

This seems to imply that one value is less precise than the other, which shouldn't be the case. I'd like to show the longitude value as "-75.6120" with the trailing 0 (ideally losing both the degree symbols as well, if possible).

I have played around quite a bit with the recommendations provided here, under the **Decimal Degree Parts** section, without success:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/add-and-modify-dynamic-text.htm

I am likely just missing some combination of tags, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried adding the "format=" tag? as in, format="long"

Comment: I have, but no avail--in this case, the "format" tag doesn't seem to have any impact.

Comment: I did not mention this in the original question, but this same sequence of tags performs as expected in ArcMap. For example, "-76.0000" will display correctly in ArcMap.